# Comparison order in PHP IF

Tags: php, if-statement, comparison

I'm pretty sure that there is no difference between this

```
if ($value === true)
```

and this

```
if (true === $value)
```

For me it always seems confusing. I used to think that it's a *'bad unconventional style of new developers'*. Furthermore, my boss told me never to do such a thing.

But today I was looking through [Slim](http://www.slimframework.com/)'s source code, written by the guy who created [PHP: The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/), and saw [this](https://github.com/slimphp/Slim/blob/2.x/Slim/Slim.php#L341) *(line 341)*.

```
if (true === $value) {
    $c['settings'] = array_merge_recursive($c['settings'], $name);
}
```

I'm sure a guy like Josh Lockhart wouldn't do something like this if it was considered a bad practice. So what's with this order? Is it some kind of an old tradition?

Comment: Some people prefer to put the literal first in order to prevent accidentally assigning instead of checking for equality.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions

Comment: @Rizier123, thanks, I never heard of that name.

Comment: I think it's good to question things like this that look weird to you. I'm not referring to this specific thing or to any specific person, but in general the fact that someone seems like they should know what they're doing does not automatically mean that the weird-looking thing they are doing is a good idea.

Comment: "Bad practice" can be a very subjective term and will vary from code base to code base. I am aware that this is called a "Yoda Condition" but I would like to shed some light on the [**Comparison with Various Types**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) table because it is possible that this `if()` was purposely written this way to achieve a certain type-juggling order. The only sure-fire answer is going to come from the author of that line of code and everything here is conjecture.

Comment: Had the comparison been written with a `===` then there is no doubt that this can be classified as a case of Yoda Condition

Comment: But since `===` is usually uncommon (for folks, who also code in strongly typed languages) and the person is consciously typing **three** equals doesn't that mean that the chance of mistyping is very low?
And what about the refactoring? Why not remove it? Because for people who use this practice this is perfectly fine?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is colloquially referred to as ['Yoda Conditions'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions).  The reasoning behind their usage is because sometimes people make mistakes.  In the context of an `if` statement, this is one such mistake that is sometimes made:

```
if($value = 42)
```

Notice there is no double equals sign (`==`).  This is a valid statement and is not a syntax error. It is possible that it would cause huge disruptions with the code that follows it, and it is very hard to identify quickly.  Yoda conditions get around this by reversing the conditional expression:

```
if(42 = $value)
```

This is *not* a valid statement and is a syntax error, and those are generally reported with a line number included, so they're pretty easy to find.

> <sub>*"Syntax error you have. Line 73 do something else you must." -- Yoda's compiler, probably*</sub>

Whether or not you actually think they're good or bad is up to personal preference and style. In some cases of popular frameworks (such as [Wordpress](https://make.wordpress.org/core/handbook/best-practices/coding-standards/php/#yoda-conditions)), Yoda conditions are actually part of the official coding standards.  The major critique against them is that, to some, they decrease readability of the code without providing any real major benefit.

As @MonkeyZeus pointed out in a comment to the question, sometimes people do actually *mean* to only use a single equals sign inside of an `if` condition:

```
if($iMustHaveAValue = functionCallThatCanFail()) {
    // Rest assured, $iMustHaveAValue has a truthy value.
}
```

Since [the value of an assignment operation is the value assigned](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php), the value that is evaluated by the `if` condition in this case (and in the original case which was unintended) is whatever value happened to be assigned.

Comment: great answer. For this you should get gold medal. :-)